# Properly splitting YOLO3 model output name to obtain 3 variables and get the best model

Tags: python, regex, tensorflow, machine-learning, split

I have a lot of files, which are a result of machine learning with YOLO model, generated by Tensorflow.

Each filename is named:

```
detection_model-ex-013--loss-0016.228.h5
```

With the only differences, being:

013 - epoch/generationNumber

0016 - loss (kind of accuracy, but from training PoV)

228 - additional precision of loss (I think, but I'm not sure yet, so I consider it as separate for now)

It would be pretty simple, but it's a combination of dashes, underscores and dots, given that I'm pretty new to python and what it's capable of, I couldn't find any solution that would fit this filename and I'm having difficulties writing a regexp for this.

For now my python "logic" selects the model solely based on which file was the last one saved, which is a start, but it's far from ideal.

```
def findBestModel():  # "best" model is currently just the last model in directory
last_model = max(glob.glob('data/models/*.h5'), key=os.path.getmtime)
print('Selected model: ' + last_model)
return last_model
```

What would be the right way to actually make findBestModel() return those 3 variables that I need, from each filename, without making it overcomplicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) to return a `match object` from each of the files you already obtained with `glob.glob`. The use of `re.match` with named groups will result in a dictionary with 3 separated values from your file name: epoch, loss and precision loss. The files can then be sorted using the `key` parameter from `sorted` using the loss value (`int(x.group('loss')`) returned by the regex. The `match object` has the attribute `string` that can be used to return the string passed to `match()`, which will correspond to the path to your best model.

```
data
└── models
    ├── detection_model-ex-002--loss-3416.127.h5
    ├── detection_model-ex-013--loss-0016.228.h5
    ├── detection_model-ex-2462--loss-0173.093.h5
    ├── detection_model-ex-486--loss-1933.981.h5
    └── detection_model-ex-83713--loss-0001.048.h5
```

```py
import glob
import re

def findBestModel():
    models = []
    for model in glob.glob('./data/models/*.h5'):
        m = re.match(
            r'.*?-(?P<epoch>\d+)--' +
            r'loss-(?P<loss>\d+)\.' +
            r'(?P<precision>\d+)\.h5'
        , model)
        models.append(m)

    sorted_models = sorted(models, key=lambda x:int(x.group('loss')))
    return sorted_models[0].string

best_model = findBestModel()
print(best_model) # './data/models/detection_model-ex-83713--loss-0001.048.h5'
```